# Mysql Percentages with multiple Group By

Tags: mysql, group-by, percentage

I'm getting stuck on what it seems an easy MySQL task: counting data as PERCENTAGES of subtotals, given by the "WITH ROLLUP" instruction.

I've searched the Internet a lot, by couldn't find something that works when you have to calculate PARTIAL percentages (that is, percentages when you have GROUPED BY multiple columns)

Here is my query:

```
SELECT elements.*, plans.*, workers.*, COUNT(action) AS counter
FROM elements
JOIN plans ON elements.id_piano = plans.id_piano 
JOIN workers ON plans.id_collaboratore = workers.id_collaboratore 
GROUP BY id_agency, category, action WITH ROLLUP
```

How can I calculate each "counter" as a PERCENTAGE of the relative subtotal which the "WITH ROLLUP" instruction gives??

Really sorry for what is probably a trivial question, but just cannot get it done.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

Here is what I get now:

```
AGENCY | CATEGORY   | ACTION      | COUNTER

Alfa   | Skill      | E-learning  | 3

Alfa   | Skill      | Coaching    | 2

Alfa   | Skill      | NULL        | 5

Alfa   | Attitude   | on-the-job  | 2 

Alfa   | Attitude   | NULL        | 2

Alfa   | NULL       | NULL        | 7
```

and so on...

Here is what I would like to have:

```
AGENCY | CATEGORY   | ACTION      | PERCENTAGE

Alfa   | Skill      | E-learning  | 60%

Alfa   | Skill      | Coaching    | 40%

Alfa   | Skill      | NULL        | 5

Alfa   | Attitude   | on-the-job  | 100%

Alfa   | Attitude   | NULL        | 2

Alfa   | NULL       | NULL        | 7
```

and so on...

In other words, I would like to calculate in some way the percentage relative to the first GROUP BY criteria.

Comment: Hi, it would be helpful is you post an example of the result you are getting, plus an example of the result you would like to get.

Comment: You're right @Galz ... I've edited the post. Thanks for your interest!